# Python - regex - sorting Japanese addresses

Tags: python, regex

I have to scrub a lot of Japanese addresses. This regex works on two regex test sites but I don't get the same results in my Windows terminal; I'm using Python 2.7.8 on Windows 7.

Here are the results from pythonregex.com:

```
string = "北海道札幌市西区二十四軒１条７丁目"
regex = re.compile("(.{2,3}?[県|道|府|都]{1})?((?:.+?市.+?区)|(?:.+?郡.+?町)|(?:.+?[市|区|町|村]))?([^0-9]+)?([0-9]+)?(?:[－|-]([0-9-]+))?")
r = regex.search(string)
r
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x350aeaba58a52420>
regex.match(string)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x350aeaba58a524e8>

# List the groups found
r.groups()
(u'\u5317\u6d77\u9053', u'\u672d\u5e4c\u5e02\u897f\u533a',u'\u4e8c\u5341\u56db\u8ed2\uff11\u6761\uff17\u4e01\u76ee', None, None)
```

This properly gives me three groups:

```
 北海道
 札幌市西区
 二十四軒１条７丁目
```

But on my terminal the same code produces this:

```
regex = re.compile("(.{2,3}?[県|道|府|都]{1})?((?:.+?市.+?区)|(?:.+?郡.+?町)|(?:.+?[市|町|村]))?([^0-9]+)?([0-9]+)?(?:[－|-]([0-9-]+))?")
r = regex.search(string)
r
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x00000000020FED20>
r.groups()
(None, '\x96k\x8aC\x93\xb9\x8eD\x96y\x8es\x90\xbc\x8b\xe6','\x93\xf1\x8f\\\x8el\x8c\xac\x82P\x8f\xf0\x82V\x92\x9a\x96\xda', None, None)
```

This gives me no matching first group, and lumps the second and third one together. Yet on 2 different Python regex testing sites, I got the desired results (the address broken into 3 separate strings). What is wrong on my terminal?

Thank you.

Comment: I've noticed that in the first bit of code, you called `regex.match(string)` while in the second bit of code, you didn't. That might have something to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

probably you need to add coding on the script header:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/

And if it doesn't works than you should try to define the strings as unicode strings:

```
u"I'm a string"
```

And if it still doesn't works, try to substitute the Japanese kanji chars to their unicode code points.

```
u"\u23ef"
```

More on this:
https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#unicode-strings

Comment: I'll try that. The final product can't be in Unicode so I'll eventually have to remove it, but for testing that out I can use Unicode.

Comment: @Tensigh At the end you can just use `str.decode('utf-8')`, replacing `str` with the variable of your choice to get rid of the encoding.

Comment: @Tensigh What do you mean by "can't be in Unicode"? The code itself or the the application? Because these are two different things...

Comment: @Lester, sorry if I wasn't clear. The final output file can't be in Unicode. The files I'm converting get uploaded to a website that only accepts Shift-JIS encoding. You have NO IDEA how much easier this task would be if I could switch to Unicode (not to mention Unicode is standardized!)

Comment: I see, but if you decode Shift-JIS to unicode string and do your computations and then encode to Shift-JIS is not acceptable? Or to be more concrete, if you decode Shift-JIS encoded bytes to unicode string and than immediately converting it back doesn't result the same byte sequence? I mean, how I think about these char table differences is: **utf-8, Shift-JIS, ascii** whatever **is how we store the data on the disk** and the database, and **unicode is how we work with it in the memory**...

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `u`   while assigning the input string  to a variable  so that python would take it as an unicode string and also you need to include `re.UNICODE` modifier in the regex compilation code.

```
>>> string = u"北海道札幌市西区二十四軒１条７丁目"
>>> regex = re.compile(u"(.{2,3}?[県|道|府|都]{1})?((?:.+?市.+?区)|(?:.+?郡.+?町)|(?:.+?[市|町|村]))?([^0-9]+)?([0-9]+)?(?:[－|-]([0-9-]+))?", re.UNICODE)
>>> r = regex.search(string)
>>> r
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f1e45714dd8>
>>> r.groups()
(u'\u5317\u6d77\u9053', u'\u672d\u5e4c\u5e02\u897f\u533a', u'\u4e8c\u5341\u56db\u8ed2\uff11\u6761\uff17\u4e01\u76ee', None, None)
```

Comment: Okay, I'll try that here. The final result can't be in Unicode so I'll have to remove it for the final product, but at least for testing I'll try it with Unicode.